# Is there a way to Force a DX Feature Level?

Tags: directx

Apparently the [fix for a game breaking bug](http://steamcommunity.com/app/210970/discussions/3/458606877334626776/#c458606877335204782) in the newly released The Witness is to just use the DX feature level 11.0 instead of 11.1; But the update is not yet out for all platforms. Is there a way to tell an application, or just the entire computer, to prefer a specific feature level? Or a program that will edit an exe to use a different feature level? Or anything of this sort?

Comment: No;  The "fix" is much more then a binary edit, it is a complete recompile of the program basically.

Comment: @Ramhound Accounting to the thread not everyone necessarily was using 11.1 to begin with (the program supports a range of feature levels: 10,0, 10,1, 11,0, and 11.1, if its internal text is to be trusted), and the program itself used no 11.1 features.

Comment: [What feature level you actually use would be hardware dependent.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476876(v=vs.85).aspx) If the software didn't take advantage of the 11.1 feature level in some capacity, there wouldn't be a bug.  Its obvious there is DX11 code, that exists within the application itself, that requires that feature level hence the bug.  So if people were using 11.0 then their hardware didn't support 11.1

Comment: @Ramhound OK, is there a way to tell my computer that it does not support 11.1?

Comment: That's your video driver and the GPU it detects

Answer (score 1):

yeah use dxcpl to use 12.1 feature level without problem since it just uses an un-hardcoded override, set it to application controlled, should give a nice fps and gfx boost at the same time

Comment: This should be a comment.

Answer (score 1):

As said in the other lowbrow answer, you [can use](https://steamcommunity.com/groups/TheUsefulWindowsGroup/discussions/0/2741975115082003449/) the DirectX Control Panel (only remember it [installs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/gaming/use-the-directx-runtime-and-visual-studio-graphics-diagnostic-features) through the new Windows settings menu, not the old school control panel). "*Disable Feature Level Upgrade*" may also be a [worthy](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a1cc57e4-4f26-4fc4-934d-30e1c1c681c5/what-is-feature-level-upgrade-?forum=wingameswithdirectx) alternative to outright limiting in certain situations.

And if your hardware supports Vulkan, [DXVK](https://github.com/doitsujin/dxvk) is a valid solution too (set `d3d11.maxFeatureLevel` in the local config file).